# RegEx don allow leading 0 in phone number 

Tags: php, regex

So far I have simple "numbers" only ...

```
/^[0-9]+$/
```

How can it be done to not allow leading zero (not start with zero) or preg_replace that would remove all spaces and leading zero ?
Thank You

Comment: Ummm...don't all phone numbers begin with 0? Or is that just in the UK.

Answer (score 5):

```
/^[1-9][0-9]+$/
```

Comment: Just a quick note to say that these should all use `*`, not `+`, or they will incorrectly reject single digit numbers.

If you are really matching integers, you may want to add `0|-?` at the beginning to match zero and negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Only numbers not starting with 0:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]+$/
```

Remove all leading spaces and zero:

```
$num = preg_replace('/^(?:0|\s)*([0-9]+)$/', '\1', ' 0999');
```

To remove all spaces in string, also those not leading, use str_replace. It can be done with regex, but if you are going to loop many numbers that would be slower.

Comment: Hi All
Thank you for your answers.
I need this for the validation in forms ...
as all mobile phones starts with 0 (as far as i know even here in Sweden)
I need a dropdown list will ready country call codes and later combine mobile number there should not be a zero ...
example 46  700700555  in order to send SMS verification code ...
now is the problem where to find ready data with countries and their call codes.
Thank you to all of you, this was very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[^0][0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(^([1-9]{1})+([0-9]{9})+$
```

This is the code for phone number 10 characters long and does not start with zero.

Comment: The `+` after each group means "one or more", so this matches **ten or more** ten digits.  Also, `[1-9]{1}` is exactly the same as `[1-9]`; the pseudo-quantifier `{1}` never has any effect.